# How can I access an IBOutlet outside the class?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `XIB` where I want to change a label text. There I created a `function` to set the label text.

In another Controller I am using that `xib` and I want to change that label in this controller. How can I access that label? Now I am doing something but I think e recreate the view and the label is not updated.

**XIB class**

```
import UIKit

class MessageView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var messageLabel: UILabel!

    func setMessage(error: String) {
        self.messageLabel.text = error
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
func updateMessage(error: Error){
       let messageView = MessageView()
       messageView.setMessage(error: error.localizedDescription)
 }
```

Comment: you are creating a NEW copy of the message view. if you actually want to change the text on the other view controller you are best using a delegate method to tell the view controller to update its own message with this new text

Comment: In addition to @Scriptable comment "you are creating a NEW copy of the message view": And it's not one linked with the Xib, so you should get a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error, because `messageLabel` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not calling the instance of the messageView that you need to change the label text on, instead you are creating a new instance of the messageView and then changing the label.

The best course of action would be to use a protocol / delegate pattern to communicate between the objects and change the text from there.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add reference of the messageView inside your viewcontroller. If your using storyboards which I assume you are just add `@IBOutlet weak var messageView : MessageView!` and then simply you can access the label like so `messageView.messageLabel.text = “some message”`

Or just use protocols and delegates.